# JQuery gets sreen size and php generates the images ¿good way?

Tags: php, jquery, loading, screen-size

Im developing a stadistics panel for users, where the images shown are bandwith usage stadistics (from one day, from 2 days, etc.). I was going to use only php, with frames, but I would like to have a more dinamic design so the images and the design could fit the user screen size, so I'm trying with JQuery to ask for the user resolution and then generate the exact images with php.

The Javascript does the screen size reading (imgsize()) and passes the values to the php script (stats_generatemain(tipo)). The php script generates the image and then the Javascript reloads the image div container (#mstats) to show the new php generated image.

Is this a good way to do it? Would you do it another way?

Thanks very much.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
      cache: false
    });

    function imgsize() {

      var myWidth = screen.availWidth;
      var myHeight = screen.availHeight;
      myRatio = myWidth / myHeight;
      myWidth = myWidth - 504;
      myHeight = myWidth / myRatio;

      var dim = new Array(2);
      dim[0] = myWidth;
      dim[1] = myHeight;
      return dim;
    }

    function mstats_resize_start() {
      var dim = imgsize();
      $('#mstats').width(dim[0]).height(430);
    }

    function stats_generatemain(tipo) { 
        if(tipo==''){tipo=1;}
        else{tipo=parseInt(tipo);}
        var dim = imgsize();
        $.ajax({ 
             url: 'stats_generatemain.php',
             type: 'get',
             data: {imsi: '214290000000003',tipo: tipo, w: dim[0], h: 430},
             beforeSend: function(){
                $("#mstats").hide();
                $('#mloading').show();
             },
             success: function(){
                var href = "./TEMP/trafico-214290000000003-main.jpg?" + Math.random();
                $("#mstats").attr("src", href);
             },
             complete: function(){
                $('#mloading').hide();
                $("#mstats").show();
             }
        });
    }

    stats_generatemain(1);

    $("a.link").live('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var tipo = this.href.split(/=/)[1];
      stats_generatemain(tipo);
    });

    $('li > a').click(function () {
      $('li').removeClass();
      $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    });


    jQuery.event.add(window, "load", mstats_resize_start);

  });
</script>
```

Comment: I would suggest making it respond on the server end:  Either 1. have it render faster, or 2. have the call be non-blocking, with a cache: the first request triggers the (background) generation and returns a url at which the image will be created.  The JS then repeatedly (ever 1s or so) requests the generated image, until it exists.  The additional load for the additional requests should be minimal, as they are simple file-get requests.  Bonus points if you make the file name a non-random hash of the input, so if that (or another) user requests the exact same thing, it's not regenerated.

Comment: You seem to be making this very complicated. Is those images static or dynamic? If static use the cache. If dynamic still use the cache for a reasonable time before a frefresh is required.

Comment: They are dinamic images. You have a menu with links to each image. Each image is an stadistics image for a specific user. Each time the user click on one of the items in the menu, the image is generated in php and then loaded in the page with JQuery.

Directly generating/showing the image in php doesn't take too long, it's reasonable. But with JQuery the response it's really bad.

Comment: I was going to use only php with iframes, loading directly each php, but it was better to know the user screen size to generate and show the images acvording to their screen size so I ended up using JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be over-thinking this... why not just use responsive design / fluid images? Apply a class to your image that uses the following css:

```
max-width:100%;
```

Height will be automatically calculated.

I'd suggest looking at [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) if you want a nice responsive design framework. If you're not too good at designing things, bootstrap can help take much of the work load off and allow you to focus on the programming side.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery gets sreen size and php generates the images ¿good way?

**from your subject and title I say this answer:**

```
.screenSize{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  visibility:hidden;
  display:none;
 }
```

and this is your jquery code:

```
$(function(){
   var width=$(".screenSize").width();
   var height=$(".screenSize").height();
 })
```

and do other what you want with php, You can send your data with ajax and do something